# Outlook Node.js add-on not moving mail to another folder on outlook window desktop application

Tags: node.js, outlook, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-addins

> I have made an outlook web-add in using Node.js which performs the
>   action of moving mail to another folder (like spam) on button click.
>   The add-in is deployed on a server. It is perfectly working for the
>   outlook web-app but the same add-in is not performing this action on
>   the outlook desktop application.

Why is this happening and what is the solution?

Comment: How are you moving the email - with Graph or EWS? Are you receiving a particular error for the move operation? Have you verified through debugging that the failure occurs on the move operation? Is this for Outlook for Windows or Mac?

Comment: I am using Microsoft simple move API. There is no error for the move operation. It's not working both Window and Mac.  Actually, this a simple add-on when a person clicks on the add-on then mail move to the spam folder. It perfectly works in outlook web add-in and not work in the desktop application.

Comment: Note that in Outlook desktop, any item open in a full window will not close if you move the email to another folder. Also, any selected item will experience a notable delay before you see the email disappear after it is moved. Does this help?

Comment: No @EricLegault

Comment: Can you share your code?